# onmouseover and onmouseout fade effect

Tags: fadein, fadeout, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm looking for a solution to add a fadein and fadeout effect to this line of code:

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/2.jpg'"      
onmouseout="this.src='images/1.jpg'" alt="fade_me" />
```

Does anyone have any simple solutions without this becoming too complex? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know about complexity, but this works pretty well.

http://jsfiddle.net/8KFT8/1/

```
<style>
    .container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .container img {
        position: absolute;
        transition: opacity .5s ease;
    }
    .container img:hover {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <img src="images/2.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
</div>
```